# cordova can't support https in building a release android app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, https

I hava a problem of Angular $http service in building release app by using cordova.
In my Angular JS control:

I use a resolve in a state of $stateProvider

```js
  resolve: {
    articleList: function($http) {
      return $http.get('https://www.zhanglun.me/article/mobie-list/').error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(＂data: "＋data);
        console.log(status: " + status);
      }).
      then(function(result) {
        return  result.data.data;

      })
    }
  }
```

It's work well in my chrome.And the error function  will not set off.
When I begin build in cordova,it's ok when I use `cordova build android`.
I get the debug app. When I begin use `cordova build android --release`.
I get the release app.but it has the problems, I get a error when I ask the https request

> In the liveboard(ionic debug tools), I find that the error was, my 
>   request return

**`data: null`**
  **`status: -1`**

It's really amazing!I get `-1` status.I find a lot infos of angular service ,but I can't
solve it.But when I try to use `http` instead of `https`.It's also work
in the release app.
Does anyone meet this problem before? my cordova version is `6.2.0`.